# What does "org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1711]: " mean in the systemd journal?

Tags: fedora, gnome, systemd-journald

```
$ journalctl -b
...
Mar 23 18:18:50 alan-laptop pkexec[31408]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1001)
Mar 23 18:19:47 alan-laptop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1711]: libinput error: client bug: timer event5 debounce short: offset negative (-3ms)
...
```

I understand the first line as a log message from PID 31408, which is an instance of the `pkexec` command.

But I'm 100% sure I don't have an executable called `org.gnome.Shell.desktop` anywhere.  A file does exist with that name, but it's an XDG desktop file.

```
$ find -xdev -name 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop*' 2>/dev/null
./usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Shell.desktop
$ ls -l ./usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Shell.desktop
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 8179 Jan 22 10:19 ./usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Shell.desktop
```

### Question

Why doesn't this log message show `gnome-shell[1711]` instead?

How is this implemented?

Did someone think it would be more useful this way?  If so, why?

### Environment

Fedora 27

- systemd-234-10.git5f8984e.fc27.x86_64
- gnome-session-3.26.1-1.fc27.x86_64

Comment: Note that you can ask a _different_ question about _another_ Desktop Bus server, for which there is a similar effect but a quite different answer.  You've happened to pick a software that is a special case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: It's GNOME Shell that decided to do that. They run multiple applications (applets) inside the same process, so they decided to use the XDG menu specifications as the "tag" to attach to the messages.

Full explanation below...

---

So the journal synthesizes the syslog-like message that you see from the internal fields stored with each message. (You can see the internal fields by using the `-o verbose` format.)

The field that usually carries the program name, a.k.a. the "tag", is stored in the [SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.journal-fields.html#SYSLOG_FACILITY=) field.

(Other programs make use of the SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER. For instance, `logger` will by default send the tag from the user who's calling it and you can override it using the `-t` option.)

There are 3 main ways to log to the journal, either by using the traditional [syslog(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog) interface, by writing to stdout or stderr from a systemd service, or by using the native journal interface.

GNOME Shell uses the native journal interface, in particular, the [sd_journal_stream_fd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_journal_stream_fd.html) API. That function takes an identifier as first argument, which is then used as SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER of messages sent through that stream.

The GNOME Shell code that initializes the journald stream can be found in [src/shell-app.c](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/3.28.0/src/shell-app.c#L1171), and tracing back the used `appid` to the caller shows that it is set using [g_app_info_get_id](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GAppInfo.html#g-app-info-get-id).

Looking up g_app_info_get_id, you'll see that the ID is platform-specific, but "on Unix this is the desktop file id from the xdg menu specification", which matches what you're observing.

The code in src/shell-app.c is preceded by a comment that explains the rationale:

```
/* This sets up the launched application to log to the journal
 * using its own identifier, instead of just "gnome-session".
 */
```

In other words, GNOME Shell runs multiple applications (through applets), so GNOME Shell developers thought it would be more appropriate to use the XDG menu specifications in the log messages, so you could tell which applet is generating it...

---

These logging streams may also be inherited by any child processes, such as Xwayland.  In this case, the PID following the tag appears to refer to gnome-shell, the process that opened the stream_fd, and not the child process which writes the message to the fd.  The log message below shows a crash of the Xwayland server, but the PID 3493 is that of gnome-shell, not Xwayland.

> Mar 17 18:08:39 alan-laptop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3494]: (EE) Caught signal 7 (Bus error). Server aborting