# How do I see the logs for the Xwayland server started by Gnome?

Tags: fedora, xorg, gnome, wayland

I am using Fedora Workstation 27.  Specifically, `gnome-session-3.26.1-1.fc27.x86_64`.

I know that Xwayland only serves X11 applications, while native Wayland apps are served directly by `gnome-shell`.  I specifically want to look for log messages from the Xwayland server.

---

The directory `~/.local/share/xorg/` is empty.  I have tried the journal:

```
# journalctl -b /usr/bin/Xwayland
-- Logs begin at Fri 2017-04-21 15:22:01 BST, end at Fri 2018-03-23 23:45:13 GMT. --
-- No entries --
```

```
# journalctl -b | grep -i 'wayland.*]: '
#
```

It doesn't show anything, even though the second approach works fine to search for "gnome-session".

It looks like Xwayland is connected to the journal, through the exact same sockets as gnome-shell.  And if you look at the full list of open files with `lsof`, Xwayland does not have any log file open.

```
$ lsof -p 20554 | grep " [0-2][ur]"
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1002/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
Xwayland 20554 alan    0r      CHR                1,3      0t0    12290 /dev/null
Xwayland 20554 alan    1u     unix 0x0000000000e7d1ab      0t0  1945828 type=STREAM
Xwayland 20554 alan    2u     unix 0x00000000a0ce92a9      0t0  1945829 type=STREAM
$ lsof -p 20518 | grep " [0-2][ur]"
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1002/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
gnome-she 20518 alan    0r      CHR                1,3       0t0    12290 /dev/null
gnome-she 20518 alan    1u     unix 0x0000000000e7d1ab       0t0  1945828 type=STREAM
gnome-she 20518 alan    2u     unix 0x00000000a0ce92a9       0t0  1945829 type=STREAM

$ lsof -p 20554
Xwayland 20554 alan    0r      CHR                1,3      0t0    12290 /dev/null
Xwayland 20554 alan    1u     unix 0x0000000000e7d1ab      0t0  1945828 type=STREAM
Xwayland 20554 alan    2u     unix 0x00000000a0ce92a9      0t0  1945829 type=STREAM
Xwayland 20554 alan    3u     unix 0x0000000028595a37      0t0  1939422 type=STREAM
Xwayland 20554 alan    4u     unix 0x000000004eb7173c      0t0  1939418 @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 type=STREAM
Xwayland 20554 alan    5u     unix 0x00000000db8a25b3      0t0  1939419 /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 type=STREAM
Xwayland 20554 alan    6u     unix 0x0000000015c66fa0      0t0  1939441 @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 type=STREAM
Xwayland 20554 alan    7u  a_inode               0,13        0    11496 [eventpoll]
Xwayland 20554 alan    8u     unix 0x00000000c130aa15      0t0  1944439 @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 type=STREAM
Xwayland 20554 alan    9u      CHR              226,0      0t0      692 /dev/dri/card0
Xwayland 20554 alan   10u      CHR              226,0      0t0      692 /dev/dri/card0
Xwayland 20554 alan   11u     unix 0x00000000313e2f4a      0t0  1945251 @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 type=STREAM
Xwayland 20554 alan   12u     unix 0x000000002c480fb6      0t0  1948769 @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 type=STREAM
Xwayland 20554 alan   13u     unix 0x00000000fe0b74af      0t0  1946332 @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 type=STREAM
Xwayland 20554 alan   14u     unix 0x000000008b10aa34      0t0  1946568 @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 type=STREAM
Xwayland 20554 alan   15u     unix 0x0000000009a83fdb      0t0  1948183 @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 type=STREAM
Xwayland 20554 alan   16u     unix 0x00000000eca69878      0t0  1948185 @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 type=STREAM
Xwayland 20554 alan   17u     unix 0x000000003a75c3bb      0t0  1955186 @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 type=STREAM
Xwayland 20554 alan   18u     unix 0x0000000072d53ca4      0t0  1957059 @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 type=STREAM
Xwayland 20554 alan   19u     unix 0x000000001efe4b9c      0t0  1948302 @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 type=STREAM
Xwayland 20554 alan   20u     unix 0x00000000777a260e      0t0  1946959 @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 type=STREAM
Xwayland 20554 alan   21u     unix 0x00000000925c7157      0t0  1948306 @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 type=STREAM
Xwayland 20554 alan   22u     unix 0x00000000ae315ead      0t0  1955996 @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 type=STREAM
Xwayland 20554 alan   23u     unix 0x000000002edc3509      0t0  1948309 @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 type=STREAM
```

Comment: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=101756

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gnome-shell` does indeed start `Xwayland` with a journal connection.  The messages are showing in the journal with a prefix like `org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3494]:`, where 3494 is the PID of the *gnome-shell* process.

See '[What does "org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1711]: " mean in the systemd journal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/433178/what-does-org-gnome-shell-desktop1711-mean-in-the-systemd-journal)'.

This can be confusing because `gnome-shell` logs the same way and it can be very noisy; whereas Xwayland can be very quiet.  I see that Xwayland does not log any startup messages.  I only see messages logging about errors.

You can try to look for Xwayland messages with a trick along the lines

```
$ journalctl --since=-1month  | grep ': [(]..[)] ' | grep -v gdm-x-session
```

or

```
$ journalctl --since=-1month \
    | grep -E '[(]([^0-9^a-z]){2}[)]' \
    | grep -v gdm-x-session
```

---

```
Mar 18 21:15:45 alan-laptop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1133]: (EE) failed to read Wayland events: Connection reset by peer
Mar 18 21:48:01 alan-laptop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3012]: (EE) failed to read Wayland events: Broken pipe
Mar 18 21:50:06 alan-laptop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2124]: (EE) failed to read Wayland events: Connection reset by peer
Mar 19 11:03:43 alan-laptop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[29640]: (EE) failed to read Wayland events: Broken pipe
```