# How to remove bloat from journald systemlog?

Tags: gnome3, systemd-journald, bugs

**tl;dr** The "managed-by-`journald`" syslog is littered with repeated error message created by one-buggy-software. How to remove those entries from the journal?

Being one of the blessed users of freedesktop.org / redhat software package deals, I enjoy both the amenities of (a) `gnome-session` desktop and (b) `systemd` with all its beauty (such as in this case binary logs "mantained" by `journald`), all the fun invoked by `dbus` is free, its marvelous. A tiny problem is that my system log is littered by this bug
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1539258 and hence contains tons of lines like this:

```
Sep 14 17:41:13 work gnome-shell[757]: Object Shell.GenericContainer (0x55eb77514080), has been already finalized. Impossible to get any property from it.
Sep 14 17:41:13 work org.gnome.Shell.desktop[757]: == Stack trace for context 0x55eb6fa0c1a0 ==
Sep 14 17:41:13 work org.gnome.Shell.desktop[757]: #0 0x7ffc7691cd30 I   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/tweener.js:73 (0x7f8a5c0c8cd0 @ 9)
Sep 14 17:41:13 work org.gnome.Shell.desktop[757]: #1 0x7ffc7691cdd0 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/tweener.js:105 (0x7f8a5c0c8f78 @ 36)
Sep 14 17:41:13 work org.gnome.Shell.desktop[757]: #2 0x7ffc7691ce70 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/tweener.js:92 (0x7f8a5c0c8de0 @ 52)
Sep 14 17:41:13 work org.gnome.Shell.desktop[757]: #3 0x7ffc7691dd00 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:208 (0x7f8a5c0d2918 @ 54)
Sep 14 17:41:13 work org.gnome.Shell.desktop[757]: #4 0x7ffc7691de50 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:337 (0x7f8a5c0d29a0 @ 1626)
Sep 14 17:41:13 work org.gnome.Shell.desktop[757]: #5 0x7ffc7691df00 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:350 (0x7f8a5c0d2a28 @ 100)
Sep 14 17:41:13 work org.gnome.Shell.desktop[757]: #6 0x7ffc7691df90 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:365 (0x7f8a5c0d2ab0 @ 10)
Sep 14 17:41:13 work org.gnome.Shell.desktop[757]: #7 0x7ffc7691e010 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128 (0x7f8a5c0cff78 @ 386)
Sep 14 17:41:13 work org.gnome.Shell.desktop[757]: #8 0x7ffc7691e060 I   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/tweener.js:207 (0x7f8a5c0cf5e8 @ 159)
Sep 14 17:41:13 work org.gnome.Shell.desktop[757]: #9 0x7ffc7691e0d0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f8a5c0b5de0 @ 71)
Sep 14 17:41:13 work org.gnome.Shell.desktop[757]: #10 0x7ffc7691e0d0 I   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/tweener.js:182 (0x7f8a5c0cf560 @ 15)
Sep 14 17:41:13 work org.gnome.Shell.desktop[757]: == Stack trace for context 0x55eb6fa0c1a0 ==
```

Being delighted with hight resource use (since contrary to some believe, the binary format is by no means a more compact format), I seek to purge those log entries from the journal that are created by `org.gnome.*`. As an user of the `journalctl` software I hope to receive an answer how this software would enable me to remove the unwanted content from the syslog.

If there was a way to configure `journald` to proactively put such log input directly into `/dev/null` , I would be even more delighted.

Comment: I don't think you can. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/170469/22142 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/433178/22142

Comment: There is a (now somewhat outdated answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/350640/24394 ) which used python-systemd to access journald via python bindings and basically at least seems to claim to produce pruned files. Which motivated me ansking the less `python`y and more general question how to do it.

Comment: _purge those log entries from the journal_ […] _remove the unwanted content from the syslog_  Which is it?  The journal?  Or the syslog?

Comment: @JdeBP I mean the files and the content associated with the `journald` software.